# Random rename all files

Tags: php, file, rename

I am trying to write a script that does the following but I am unsure where to start:

Gets all the files in a dir - both `*.JPG and *.jpg`
Renames the above files starting from `00` - using the `RANDOM()` function and saves them as .JPG
Displays a success message when done.

Currently they are "RANDOM_FILENAME.JPG or .jpg"  I am wanting `ranNum.JPG` in the end a random image with a random number

I know that I will have to get all the files in the folder and possibly explode them but I just confused at the best `5.*` way to do this

Comment: where does the `random` fit here?

Comment: still dont get it. `starting for 00` means "a sequence"... give an example. 00,56,99,23 ? Why two zeros? Should it always be two digits?

Comment: If you use `random()` what happens if you get a repeated name? Why do it randomly instead of sequentially?

Comment: Do you want ALL the files, or just `*.jpg` and `*.JPG`?

Comment: @Barmar I understand what you mean - I know with what I am using it for there is not a double up on the current file names.  I am making a photo slideshow and I want them mixed and not in a sequence.  I want both image types and to rename them all with `.JPG`

Comment: I'd recommend numbering them like 00-99, then within your photo slideshow (assuming it's with code as well), shuffle if then. If you depend on the numbering for your order, then it's still going to be the same order every time anyways. And plus, they're currently `RANDOM_FILENAME` already, so it doesn't make sense to make them even more random, now does it.

Comment: @DaveChen Not within code sadly

Comment: I think I understand now. Essentially, you want to be able to run your script, so that it randomizes all the names of the images, thus creating a new order for your slideshow.

Comment: If your goal is to randomise your slideshow, do that in code. Don't actually rename all physical files, that's madness.

Comment: @deceze Slideshows not in code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
// getting the list of files
$files = glob('my/dir/*.[jJ][pP][gG]');

foreach($files as $file) 
{
    // here: trying to find a random name.
    // repeat, if such a file already exists 
    do {
        $number = mt_rand(0, 999999);
        $new_name = dirname($file) .'/'. sprintf("%06d", $number) .'.JPG';
    } 
    while(is_file($new_name));

    // now, all we need is love!
    rename ($file, $new_name);
}

echo "Successfully renamed ".count($files)." files!";
```

This will rename them randomly, like 528989.JPG, 112344.JPG, 003424.JPG, etc.